# File links in Markdown-syntax

Tags: markdown

To link to ***another*** file (or image) within my `.md`-file, I would normally have to *save a copy of that file (image) in the same folder as my .md-file*, i.e. create a duplicate file, right.

I could then write such `.md`-code:

```
[Link to duplicate file](MyFileName.cs)
```

or:

```
[Link to duplicate image](ImageName.png)
```

Is there a better way to do it without creating duplicate files (images)?

Something like...

```
[Link to original file](file:///C:/User/Pictures/ImageName.png)
```

...just so that it works?